# Is there any simple way to change one line in a lot of files?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I'm trying to use PHP CodeSniffer, and here's the result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
A TOTAL OF 3008 ERROR(S) AND 380 WARNING(S) WERE FOUND IN 46 FILE(S)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

There a a lot of small changes on one line (for example: change `@author Olivier Pons` to `@author    Olivier Pons <olivier.pons@gmail.com>`) that I'd like to do via a shell script, or even better, via a command line, and (if possible) using regular expression.

Do you have any idea/suggestion/working solution for this problem?

Thank you!

(Note: I've already read [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-replace-a-line-in-text-file-631208/) but it didn't help me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what didn't help you in the link you provided, but `sed` seems like the right tool for this. It supports regular expression replacements, and if you pass it `-i` it will change files in-place:

```
$ sed -i 's/@author Olivier Pons/& <olivier.pons@gmail.com>/g' /path/to/your/file /path/to/another/file ...
```

(The `&` in the replacement is a shorthand that means "include the entire match")

Comment: Wrapping in `find /where/your/files/live -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i s/see/above {} \;` should deal with the whole lot of them, I suppose

Comment: Is there any way to replace using a regular expression (no matter the number of spaces between author and "olivier pons"), **and** replace only the first match found?

Comment: @OlivierPons It's somewhat more complicated, since `sed` is intended to operate per-line, not per file, but this should work: `sed '0,/@author \+Olivier Pons/ s/@author \+Olivier Pons/& <olivier.pons@gmail.com>/'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use sed.

For example.

```
sed -i "s/@author Olivier Pons/@author Olivier Pons <olivier.pons@gmail.com>/g" `grep "@author Olivier Pons" -rl YOUR_FILE_DIR`
```

Comment: Please don't (ab)use command substitution like that.  It's fragile and inefficient and `find(1)` already exists for this purpose.